# Chemical potential of Bose–Einstein condensation

Tags: bose-einstein-condensate, chemical-potential

A problem from [Schroeder's Introduction to Thermal Physics](http://physics.weber.edu/thermal/) [1]:

> **Problem 7.66.** Consider a collection of $10\,000$ atoms of rubidium-87, conf‌ined inside a box of volume $(10^{-5}\;\mathrm{m})^3.$
>
> (**a**) Calculate co, the energy of the ground state. (Express your answer in both joules and electron-volts.)
>
> (**b**) Calculate the condensation temperature, and compare $kT_c$ to $\epsilon_0$.
>
> (**c**) Suppose that $T = 0.9T_c.$ How many atoms are in the ground state? How
>   close is the chemical potential to the ground-state energy? How many atoms are in each of the (threefold-degenerate) f‌irst excited states?
>
> (**d**) Repeat parts (**b**) and (**c**) for the case of $10^6$ atoms, conf‌ined to the same volume. Discuss the conditions under which the number of atoms in the
>   ground state will be much greater than the number in the f‌irst excited state.

(**a**) and (**b**) are easy to work out. In (**c**), I use the formula $\displaystyle N_\mathrm{excited}=\left(\frac{T}{T_c}\right)^{3/2}N, \ (T<T_c)$ to calculate how many atoms are there in the ground state. But I am completely lost about the difference between chemical potential and ground-state energy, because the book always assumes $\mu \approx 0$ when $T<T_c$. I don't think the answer should simply be $\epsilon_0$ but don't know to how to calculate.

I know this question seems to be silly, but please provide some hints about it.

#### References

1. Schroeder, D. V. *An Introduction to Thermal Physics*; Addison Wesley: San Francisco, CA, **2000**. ISBN 978-0-201-38027-9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It feels like you are going to fast in your way to think.
The difference between the chemical potential and the ground state energy is clear :

1. The ground-state energy of your system is here $\epsilon_\textbf{k}=0$ correponding to the ground-state $|\textbf{k=0}\rangle$, which is macroscopically occupied in a BEC (i.e.  $N\sim N_0$).
2. The chemical potential $\mu$ is the increment in energy that you give to your condensate by adding one particle. It is generally defined using free energy $F$ :
   $$\mu=\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial N}\right)_{V,\;T}$$

If you want to evaluate $\mu$, considere the ground-state occupation :
$$N_0=\frac{1}{e^{-\beta\mu}-1}$$

If you want $N_0$ to be the biggest possible (macroscopic occupation), you must fulfill the condition $e^{-\beta\mu}\rightarrow 1$, in other words $\mu\rightarrow 0$.

For larger resolution on $\mu$, one can do a Taylor expansion on the expression of $N_0$ :
$$N_0\underset{\mu\rightarrow 0}{\sim}-\frac{1}{\beta\mu}$$
Then,
$$\mu\simeq -\frac{1}{N_0\beta}=-\frac{k_\mathrm{B} T}{N_0}=-\frac{k_\mathrm{B} T}{N-N_\mathrm{exc}}$$